# Bug: Code block scroller hides the code

Tags: bug, design

There's an annoying bug that I've been experiencing for some time, the scroller overlays the code in a code box and hides the code itself.

It is shown best in the following screen shot:
[image]
As you can see, the scroller of the code box hides the code itself.

I'm not sure about it but I think it happens only and not always - when the code is only one line.

I'm using Chrome on MacOs

Comment: Can you check again? I think this is fixed now.

Comment: It seems like it's fixed, good job!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'am not mistaking, it's a Chrome/Chromium bug;

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914844

I got the link from that thread; [Cannot dismiss scrollbar in code box, blocks view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321136/cannot-dismiss-scrollbar-in-code-box-blocks-view)

It show how to bypass the problem too

and you can see shog9 comment's from that thread;

> Marking this "support" since it appears to be caused by a toxic
>   cocktail of Mac and Chrome - while the giants fight it out, the best
>   we can do is work around it. – Shog9♦

I did wrote that in an answer as I can't mark a duplicate there, as the original question is on metastackexchange, and migrating your question to MSE would not be a good idea IMO